# What should I watch after "Dragon Ball Z"?

Tags: chronology, suggested-order, dragon-ball-z

I'm somewhat new to the Dragon Ball universe. So far, I have watched all of the English Dragon Ball Z Kai episodes (1-98), which cover through the Cell games. Currently, I have picked up where Kai left off with the original DBZ, and now plan to watch DBZ through the end. So, what comes after the Dragon Ball Z series? I have read a little bit about titles "Dragon Ball GT" and "Dragon Ball Super"; which one should I watch first following Dragon Ball Z, in order to follow the right chronology?

Comment: This is likely largely a matter of opinion... viewing orders depend on whether you want to watch them in a "recommended" order or in the order of production. [This site](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=22315) has a recommended order that might help.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the link! I am trying to figure out the order in which the characters progress chronologically. For example, I think I read that Dragon Ball Super was produced after Dragon Ball GT, but that DBZ Super is actually a set of story arcs that occur within the greater DBZ universe before the arcs that occur in DBZ GT.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, watch the **classic Dragon Ball**, featuring the kid Son Goku. It's amazing and fun until today. The whole concept of the dragon spheres was there and after that the series turns out on a anime about strong enemies and fights.

If you stopped on Cell at the end of DB Kai you must watch the entire **Boo's saga** which starts on episode 217 on classic Dragon Ball Z.
After that, you could watch Super or get some spoilers on the **Battle of Gods (2013)** movie, which is mostly the same story, but shortened.

There's also a 2015 very good movie called **Dragon Ball Z: Resurrection 'F'** that depends on the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Dragon Ball GT and Dragon Ball Super are both sequel of Dragon Ball Z but are not connected. GT was not based on the manga by Akira Toriyama but he considers GT to be an alternate timeline.

There is no order in which to watch between the two. Super has just started and isn't complete, so you could watch all of GT now (which only has 64 episodes).

Answer (score 2):

In term of timeline, Dragon Ball Super took place 6 months after the battle of Majin Buu. It should be the next show you want to watch. It covers DBZ: Battle of Gods and Resurrection of F. It is at episode 26 (still in Resurrection of F)

Dragon Ball GT was released in 1996 with 64 episodes. While it is a sequel to DBZ, it does not follow the Dragon Ball manga series by Akira Toriyama. The series may cause a distortion.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_GT):

> Unlike the previous two anime series in the Dragon Ball franchise, Dragon Ball GT does not adapt the manga series by Akira Toriyama, but is a sequel show to the Dragon Ball Z anime with an original story using the same characters and universe.

Dragon Ball GT was created by Atsushi Maekawa to be the conclusion of the Dragon Ball Series. This could cause a distortion from the direction where the writer of Dragon Ball Z Takao Koyama wants to take the series. Dragon Ball Super manga is written by Akira Toriyama, the author who wrote the Dragon Ball manga (not DBZ). It takes place right after DBZ ended. For those who like DBZ, it is best to watch DB Super and not DB GT.

Answer (score 0):

If you finish dbz kai  after gohan defeats cell, you should watch the buu saga which starts on episode 217 of the classic Dragon Ball Z but if you want to watch where dbz kai left off at then you should start on episode 200 of the classic Dragon Ball Z

Answer (score 0):

Dragon Ball GT is based after DBZ but is an alternate timeline so its not original because that show is non cannon but what you should watch is the movies although some of them are not relevant to the story they are fun to watch and the movies made in 2013-2015 are just arcs from Dragon ball super shortened but are good because they are dubbed but the dubs for super haven't got a release date yet so if you don't mind sub's you can watch super but if u don't like sub's you can pass time by, by watching GT or other anime, I recommend One Piece, Fairy tail, Naruto